# Doctrine performance with hydration

Tags: doctrine-orm

I am having a problem with long execution times in PHP (10s) when using Doctrine2 and am wondering what solution can be applied.

I am loading an actor entity which has a 1:n relation to features. I am loading 50 actors each having 20 features which results in 1000 rows. The problem seems to be Doctrine Hydration. It doesn´t make a big difference if I am using object or array hydration. In the profiler I can see that the main impact is the method gatherRowData/hydrateRowData which are both called 13.141 times.

Is the only solution to use a plain old Mysql resultset and loop over that array? If yes I am wondering which sense it then makes to use a ORM. Hopefully someone can shed some light on this. Normally I want to have objects which can be accessed through methods like getIdentity() or which could hold some business logic e.g. for obtaining associated entities.

Best Regards
Christian

Comment: Are you loading these entities in a for loop or with one query?